# Incoming serial data is not getting printed on the console using pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

I am building a GUI in `Tkinter` and I want to receive incoming data from Serial (from a microcontroller).

Also, I want to print that out onto the `text-editor` widget in `Tkinter` (similar to the serial monitor console).

For that, I am right now trying to write a receiving code in Python without Tkinter but I am unable to receive any data in the console.

The code is as follows:

```py
import serial
import time
import threading

global serial_open
serial_open = False

def serial_read():
    global ser
    global var

    while True:
        if serial_open == True:
            var = ser.readline()
            if var != "":
                print(var)
        else:
            pass
        
        

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate = 19200)
time.sleep(3)
serial_open = True
print("COM3 Connected")
threading.Thread(target = serial_read).start()
time.sleep(10)
ser.close()

print("Disconnected")
```

Comment: Just a small advice `serial_open = False` automatically makes `serial_open` global... So, `global serial_open` isn't required.

Comment: Have you tried changing the baud rate? Which microprocessor are you talking with? Atmega? When it comes to hardware there is a whole list of things that can go wrong... Are you absolutely sure that you are in fact receiving data from the microprocessor? Have you checked it with a 3rd party software?

Comment: I am actually using an FPGA and the data is being sent through the serial interface. yes i have checked the incoming data with third party software like "Hterm" and the data is received perfectly, also after that i need to send data to the fpga to enable some outputs which i have connected. Sending programs will also be acknowleged. Thanks.